# Wath is the diference between normal python interpretated code and python executable code? is it more performant? (using py2exe for example)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know becouse as far as i know how the python code works it is slower becouse is an interpretated languaje need to do some extra work in running time thus it is slower, but if i compiled it, it wuld be more performant? or ot will be the same? and what will be the difference between them? other thean performance and when i should compile the code? when i need no other dependencis of python interpretator?, larger proyects or somthing else?

I wanted to ask because there are a lot of peopol new in programing using python and that will be very useful information to know

Comment: the whole point of py2exe is to run your code without needing to have python already installed, like to share your code with your friend/family/clients that aren't programmers or computer savvy or otherwise don't want to install it in the first place

Answer (score 1):

When you use py2exe, that basically creates a big zip file that contains your source code, the modules you need, and a copy of the Python interpreter. When you run it, it unzips into a miniature self-contained Python environment and runs the interpreter. There is no difference in performance.